# Accessing Vimeo Review page comments?

Tags: node.js, vimeo, vimeo-api

Is there any way to access Vimeo video's Review page comments via the API or any other means? These are the comments that reviewers can add to a specific time and place in the video frame. Using Vimeo API only seems to return the Review page, but not any data about the review.

Comment: Have you had a look at the [VIMEO-API -> responses -> comments](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/response/comment)?

Comment: @iLuvLogix I'm pretty sure these are comments people leave under the video, not the review page comments.

Comment: My bad - _"or any other means?"_ -> you could download the CSV file -> Downloading notes: _"If you want to save a local copy of all the notes left on your review page, you can download a CSV of all the notes left by clicking the ••• menu above the notes and selecting Download CSV. The CSV file will contain:.."_ as explained [here](https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/224818367-Video-review-page-) and then process the CSV file to your needs.. Note that only works for your account coz those reviews are somehow semi-private..